# Auth::once($credentials) always false

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.1

I have one route, this route call my controller. Inside this controller I have :

```
  $user = Auth::loginUsingId(1); // This data get from a form
  $mail = $user->email;
  $pass = $user->password;     

  $credentials = [
   'email'    => $mail,
   'password' => $pass,
  ];

  if (Auth::once($credentials)) {
      return Auth::user()->id;
  }

  return \App\Login::where('email', '=', $mail)->where('password', '=',$pass)->first(); // I can see my user, with his email and password. It is a exmplante, later when this is working I will put false
```

My model is Login.php instead of User.php

```
class Login extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{

    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    protected $table = 'logins';
    protected $fillable = ['email','password'];
    protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at_at'];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

And I change the file config/auth.php

```
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => \App\Login::class,
    'table' => 'logins',

    'password' => [
        'email'  => 'emails.password',
        'table'  => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
```

I try use the Auth::attempt() but I have the same problem, I do not understand because I can connect my database, I config the new model in config/auth ...

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No, only return false.

Comment: Are you sure the password comes in hashed? (Hash::make($password))

Comment: I FOUND THE ERROR!!! The problem is that the key is numeric if you add a letter ... works.